# Are impossible puzzles allowed?

Tags: discussion

[This question here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123/magic-square-with-the-position-of-8-fixed) involves a puzzle goal that turns out to be impossible. Are puzzle problems like this allowed in general, if it's known that they're impossible?

Comment: In addition to Kevin's answer: how do you know that the OP knew it was impossible? Maybe they were honestly asking, and the answer "That can't be done because X" will be useful to them.

Answer (score 7):

Sure.  Especially if it's something that seems like it ought to be possible, it can be an interesting answer, given an appropriate proof/explanation, that something is not, in fact, possible.

Comment: I agree, the best answer should prove that it's not possible.